# AWS - Redshift invalid query results for Decimal fields

Tags: python-3.x, database, amazon-redshift

Wrong results for Decimal fields

Language & Tools:
Python 3.8
redshift-connector
AWS Redshift

I tried to query redshift DB, (I used Python & redshift_connector as client app), when I did something like this:

```
select "price" from deal_history;
```

I got
[image]
There are some weird negative numbers which was clearly wrong as those were supposed to be history trade price of Bitcoin.
But when I used postgresql command to execute the same query, it worked perfectly, the data was fine.
The type of field "price" is DECIMAL(38, 20) btw. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Can you query for the data in the Redshift console and verify what is in the database? It is unlikely that the driver modifies the results, but rather that the import into the DB is wrong.

Comment: Hi MP24, I had found the problem, this is an issue related to redshift_connector 2.0.879 and later version, I reverted to  2.0.878, it worked fine. Need to wait for a fix for this.